# cannot start Rails after upgrade to MacOs High Sierra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv, macos-high-sierra

I have updated my system to MacOs High Sierra, but I can't start the Rails server anymore.

When I run `rails server` I get this error message:

> Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 82 total gem(s) 
>       (Gem::MissingSpecError)

also when I run 'rails -v' I get this error:

Could not find 'nokogiri' (>= 1.5.9) among 82 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

It looks like Rails is searching under `.../.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/...` but my Rails app was installed under `ruby 2.3.1`.

I tried to fix this by locally installing `ruby 2.3.1` with the command `rbenv local 2.3.1` but that didn't fix it.

How can I fix this?

Update: I fixed the issue by removing the project folder and cloning it again from github. Then I did a bundle install and now I get my Rails app up and running again.

Comment: Before trying to answer, did you run `bundle install` and made sure every gem is installed (`bundle list`)?

Comment: @aried3r yes I ran 'bundle install', that does work

Comment: Did `bundle install` not finish successfully or did it not install `nokogiri`? Did you verify `bundle list` shows `nokogiri` as installed?

Comment: What is the output of `ruby -v`? Are you certain `2.3.1` is what's being used?

Comment: Sometimes you need to uninstall and reinstall gems if you've done a big upgrade.

Comment: what does `rbenv versions` show in your project?

Comment: @Tom Lord, when I type ruby -v I get 2.5.0. I don't get this, I set it to ruby 2.3.1 with rbenv local 2.3.1

Comment: @Joe rbenv versions shows 2.3.1 (set by /Users/anthonycandaele/Sites/absence_registrator/.ruby-version)

Comment: I had this same issue after upgrading to High Sierra, but cloning a fresh version of the repo didn't work for me; bundle install failed with an error while installing nokogiri. The error output directed me to check gem_make.out, which said Xcode Command Line Tools wasn't installed properly. I followed its instructions on installing it, and after that the nokogiri install completed without an error, as well as bundle install (which then includes nokogiri 1.6.5)